# What exactly happens if I enter "rm *.txt" into a terminal (emulator) on a *nix machine?

Tags: linux, file, unix, terminal

What happens exactly? Is there a linear search in the current directory and everything with a .txt extension gets deleted and that is it? Or is there something fancy in the background?

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstanding... I know what regex is and I know the "endproduct" of rm *.txt. What I am interested in, HOW it is done. How does for example what @a1ezh wrote in his/her answer ("... replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern...") happen. What happens after these files are selected for removal? "They are removed." - but how?
Edit: I have just tried the -v verbose option of rm and read the manual - yet, I am not really smarter than before.

Answer (score 1):

*.txt is expanded by the shell first, then `rm` is called on that list of arguments.

That is why sometimes you command will fail if the number of files is very large and exceeds the maximum number of parameters allowed.

Ex:

```
directory1/
    a.txt
    b.txt

cd directory1
rm *.txt
```

is equivalent to:

```
cd directory1
rm a.txt b.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion):

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and **replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern** (see Pattern Matching).

Bash substitute *.txt with actual files in directory. You can check what Bash will try to remove:

```
echo *.txt
```

Comment: Nice the suggestion to use echo *.txt.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy in background (I guess you want to know if there's a recycle bin, like in Windows).

There is not!

`rm *.txt` removes all textfiles in the directory, and they are lost for ever.